# Move logic into map in return part

Tags: reactjs, move, simplify, tsx, array.prototype.map

So I want to simplify this Code by moving it

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    const generationId: number = shuffeledIdArray[i];

    cards.push({
      element: (
        <Card
          randomId={generationId}
          hideShowCard={cardHideShowDefault}
          cards={shuffeledCards}
        />
      ),
      id: generationId.toString(),
      state: cardHideShowDefault,
      cards: shuffeledCards,
    });
  }
```

I want to move it down into this part

```
  return (
    <div className={styles.mainDiv}>
      <div className={styles.flexgameboard}>

        {cards.map((card, index) => ( //Around here//

          <div className={cardHideShowDefault} key={card.id}>
            {card.element}
          </div>
        ))}
```

So that I can get rid of the for loop and completetly rely on the map

I tried moving around and defining new Types but didnt found a Solution without another map/for which I dont want

Comment: What error or unexpected output are you getting?

Comment: None but its about simplifing

Comment: Maybe try here instead? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No @Camilo - [codereview.se] is for code that's already _finished, to the programmer's satisfaction_. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to simplify your code is to declare an array of length 16 and use it as follows:

```js
return (
  <div className={styles.mainDiv}>
    <div className={styles.flexgameboard}>
      {new Array(16).fill(0).map((item, index) => {
        const cardId = shuffeledIdArray[index];

        return (
          <div className={cardHideShowDefault} key={cardId}>
            <Card
              randomId={cardId}
              hideShowCard={cardHideShowDefault}
              cards={shuffeledCards}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```